# Halmos Finite dimensional vector spaces $\S$74 Change of orthonormal basis

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Hi I am stucked with a seemingly simple issue. This is Theorem 2 of section $\S$74 of Halmo's Finite dimensional vector spaces. I Will give my thoughts in hope someone is willing to help this poor soul.

> **Theorem.** If $A$ is a linear transformation on a complex $n$-dimensional vector space then there exists an orthonormal basis $X$ in $V$ such that $[A;X]$ is triangular, or equivalently if $[A]$ is a matrix there exists an isometric matrix $[U]$ such that $[U]^{-1}[A][U]$ is triangular.

First thing I cannot grasp is the equivalence statement. $\Leftarrow$. I understand but I cannot get why $\Rightarrow$ is equivalent.  Halmos proof uses the fact that you can find a basis for which matrix Would be triangular and splits in two cases. If the base is orthonormal, then you should be able to find $U$ such that
$[U]^{-1}[A][U]$ is triangular but why is this isometric? Now if it it is not then use gram schmidt to find an orthogonal base. This base keeps the triangular Shape I get it. But seems to me that this transformation process would be associated with a non isometric tranform (after all I am not preserving distances to make the basis orthogonal) .

Comment: Every matrix which maps an orthonormal basis to another orthonormal basis is an isometry. That should explain the first case. The second case follows from the fact that by Gram Schmidt procedure the matrix associated with the mapping from a given basis to the constructed orthonormal basis is triangular. Finally the product of two triangular matrices is triangular.

Comment: Yes any basis that maps an orthonormal basis to an orthonormal basis is isometric. But to make it triangular in the first place you dont necessarily have an isometric matrix? This is why I think to me the root of my missunderstanding is why the equivalence of two statments is valid.

Comment: The point is that the mapping from the original basis to the last one orthonormal basis (on the way there was a basis not necessarily orthonormal) is an isometry.

Comment: Let me ask this way. Where are the two orthonormal basis involved?The last one is orthonormal but for it to be an isometry there are two basis involved. As you said the original May not be orthonormal. Is it because I can  "see" /decompose into some subyacent orthonormal and from there take it to the final orthonormal?

Comment: There are two formulations of the theorem. We have a linear transformation $A$. There is an orthonormal basis such that the matrix of $A$ is triangular. Then we are not talking about any isometry. Second formulation: we pick up an orthonormal basis and $[A]$ denotes the matrix of $A$ with respect to this basis. If $[A]$ is triangular we are done. If not there is a basis with respect to which $A$ is triangular. After applying the GS procedure we get an orthonormal basis so that $A$ is triangular. The mapping from the first orthonormal basis to the last one is an isometry.